# Solved - Create A New Tab Next to Dashboard in Magento Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, database, adminhtml, grid, backend

I have created a Module and need to have a separate tab (grid) in Magento backend  (next to Dashboard or any other menu item) to display customer comments (that are stored in the separate database table of this module) in that grid.

Created a file adminhtml.xml using this article http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited/ and added the code below, but I'm getting an error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <menu>
 <cpstest translate="title" module="cpstest_productcomments">
            <title>Allow Comments</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <children>
                <example>
                    <title>CPS Product Comments</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/productcomments/index</action>
                </example>
            </children>
        </cpstest>
    </menu>
</config>
```

And this is the module's config.xml file

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cpstest_ProductComments>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cpstest_ProductComments>
    </modules>
    <frontend>    
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productcomments module="Cpstest_ProductComments">
                    <file>productcomments.xml</file>
                </productcomments>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <productcomments>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cpstest_ProductComments</module>
                    <frontName>productcomments</frontName>
                </args>
            </productcomments>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <productcomments>
                <class>Cpstest_ProductComments_Model</class>
            </productcomments>
        </models>       
         <resources>
         <productcomments_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cpstest_ProductComments</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                   <class>Cpstest_ProductComments_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!---->
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_setup>   
            <productcomments_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_write>
            <productcomments_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_read>
        </resources> 
        <helpers>
            <productcomments>
                <class>Cpstest_ProductComments_Helper</class>                                                             
            </productcomments>            
        </helpers>
    </global>
<adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <productcomments_options>
                                            <title>Product Comments</title>
                                        </productcomments_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Please add details about the error you are facing

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya  I added the error message. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if any other issue.

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya thanks so much, now that error is gone and the tab is there :)  But the link takes to 404 page.

Comment: Did you create controller file? It should be on Cpstest/ProductComments/controllers/Adminhtml/ProductcommentsController.php, if yes, please add code for your file here. Also add code for your layout file in design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/YOUR_LAYOUT_FILE.xml

Comment: My controller file is indexController.php and the layout file is in rwd theme. I added the codes for both. Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file **Cpstest/ProductComments/Helper/Data.php** with below code

```
<?php 
class Cpstest_ProductComments_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
}
```

**EDIT**
The module name you are using in your **adminhtml.xml** is wrong. Update your **adminhtml.xml** with below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <menu>
        <cpstest translate="title" module="productcomments">
            <title>Allow Comments</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <children>
                <example>
                    <title>CPS Product Comments</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/productcomments/index</action>
                </example>
            </children>
        </cpstest>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi @Jaimin Sutariya , the problem is I already had that exact same code in my helper, but still getting the error. (I cleared the cache)

Comment: @bestwebdevs, Check my edit to the answer.

Comment: I will create a separate question for the rest of the issue. Thanks for your help  @Jaimin Sutariya

Answer (score 0):

Read the below blog that is explained how to use external database connection in Magento.

[Create An External Database Connection in Magento](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-external-database-connection/)

> If you able to connect of your external database, then its the same
>   procedure to develop custom grid implementation

Comment: Thanks for your help @Supravat. Think that's not exactly what I need though.